# Running error in python when trying to filter chars from string

Tags: python, string, input

I'm trying to implement a function that gets an input string (for example: input = 1234@Hello) and the function will return only the chars (in the example: return Hello)

So I created a function that get a variable which is the input, converting one by one to char and checking if the char is a letter. if so, the function will add the letter to final string.

When I tried to run the script, and gave it input, I got the following error:
[1234HI

Traceback (most recent call last):line 6, in select_only_chars
char = chr()
TypeError: chr() takes exactly one argument (0 given)]

```
key = input()

def select_only_chars(user_input):
    full_string = user_input
    char = chr()
    final_string = ''
    for char in full_string:
        if ('a' <= char <= 'z') or ('A' <= char <= 'Z'):
            final_string += char
    return final_string

print(select_only_chars(key))
```

Comment: `char = chr()` What's that for?

Comment: to convert any letter or number to char

Comment: Delete it. It is attempting to call the `chr` function with no arguments but it requires one.

Comment: Oh my god it worked!

Comment: Just to show the power of Python: if you do `import string` then the full function body can be written as the one-liner `return ''.join(char for char in user_input if char in string.ascii_letters)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative solution

```
import string

def select_only_chars(user_input):
    full_string = user_input
    all_letters = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase
    final_string = ''
    for char in full_string:
        if char in all_letters:
            final_string += char
    return final_string

key = "1234@Hello"
print(select_only_chars(key))
```

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @Jhonny Mopp
Deleting the char = chr() variable fixed the whole code.